# Best PHP Frameworks For Apps

Tags: php, web, yii, frameworks

I would like to create a website where I can easily later add on extensions, like apps. For example, Google is a website built on apps: Search, Mail, Hangouts, Drive, etc... What is a good php framework I should use if I want to end up doing something like this? Right now I am currently exploring Yii. Also would PHP be suitable for something like this?

Comment: Any of them. Asking us to choose the "best" of anything is off-topic for Stack Overflow. There are a million frameworks, and everybody has their favourite.

Comment: any mvc framework will do fine as long as the developer is coding right, right?

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Selection of a suitable framework is up to you. If you are just exploring frameworks then Yii is good to start, however you may also check codeigniter that's very easy to learn and well documented. Secondly you asked if PHP is suitable for something like this? Yes PHP is suitable to do such applications. Zend also provides great libraries to work with if you are going to work on a rich application where you will add extensions etc later days that can be very helpful this will save your time and give you a chance to build a secure application.